"connect ECONNREFUSED" with Nginx on AWS EC2
I'm deploying my node server to AWS and came across a problem. Everytime I try to connect to my instance over HTTP I get this error

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED [INSTANCE PUBLIC IP]:80

I've deployed servers many times but this is the first time I'm facing this particular issue. Would love some help on it.
Below is some information that I've gathered to troubleshoot the issue.
Security Group Settings
PORT 80 is open
VPC Settings
All ports are open
Nginx Config
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

sudo systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-07-19 07:22:44 UTC; 17min ago
    Process: 31332 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 31333 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 31334 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 31335 (nginx)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 1114)
     Memory: 2.2M
        CPU: 54ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─31335 "nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx"
             └─31336 "nginx: worker process"

netstat -tunlp
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::3001                 :::*                    LISTEN      28321/node /home/ec 
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      28193/node /home/ec 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 172.31.17.134:68        0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 fe80::80:45ff:fef1::546 :::*                                - 

sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          permissive
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Memory protection checking:     actual (secure)
Max kernel policy version:      33

Couple of other observations to note

The instance does not have any elastic IP or load balancer attached.
Running curl http://localhost:80/ on the system does return a valid response from the Node server
Doing this curl request also logs an entry in nginx logs
No such entries are observed when making a request over the internet

Leads me to believe that the request might not be reaching Nginx or Nginx may not have the correct permissions.

Let's try to troubleshoot if the problem is in the instance network configuration or nginx configuration. Does it works If you make a request to [INSTANCE PUBLIC IP]:3000 directly?

Thank you for taking the time out for this.
[INSTANCE IP]:3000 also generates "connect ECONNREFUSED".
(Edit: Just some more info SSH with key file works just fine its just the http requests resulting in this)

perhaps check if there is a firewall enabled at OS level? also since there is no LB in front of the instance, is the instance in a public subnet (does the subnet has a route to an internet gateway)?

Ok so I had the liberty to setup a new EC2 instance since it was my account. So I setup a basic Node server and connected directly to 3000 port over the internet and it responded. Next I installed Nginx and that also worked fine. I started adding things one-by-one checking my connectivity status.
Turns out the culprit was iptables-services
Since I don't have the need for it. I just removed it from my main server and it started connecting. Though I don't know what the actual issue was since all my rules were correctly configured.
Commands to uninstall were
sudo systemctl stop iptables
sudo yum remove iptables-services


It's great you found the issue. Just for other readers. It's probably not a good idea to just blindly uninstall iptables from the EC2 instance. There are cases where iptables cannot be fully replaced by Security Groups. Check this to see some examples.
Make fully sure you don't need it before uninstalling it.

Yes it made sense in my case because I didn't need the service, but you are right mindlessly deleting it can be bad
